# It is Possible to send Push notification at specific time Using FCM IN FLUTTER

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using the Firebase Cloud MessagingPush notification service to send notifications in flutter but  I want to send notifications at a specific time like a reminder for a meeting through push notification I just want to know how can I achieve using Firebase Cloud Messaging or any other push notification service provider.

1. I already used flutter local_push_notification but the problem is notification is not showing at terminated state but it is working on the background and foreground state.
2. is there any method is available that I can use on my server where all my API is presently saved, which I using to call in a flutter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use firebase cloud functions. You should send notifications at the moment you want with cloud functions and problem should be solved.
Here is the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions).